# how to prevent excel 2010 from converting times to decimals automatically when cell is pasted

Tags: excel, excel-2010

As you might have come accross, MS Excel tends to convert times to decimal values. I do want it to convert the values automatically because I need the time value. Suppose I have following data:

Departure | Time

Istanbul    06:45
Ankara      01:30

I am using **Concatenate** function to create a desired string as **Istanbul: 08:00** and **Ankara: 18:30**. However, when I use the formula, Excel converts hours to decimals and I get **Istanbul: 0.28125** and **Ankara: 0.0625**. I do not want it to convert. How can I do this?

ps: This also happens when I copy time values from Excel to Notepad++. Moreover, when I import time values into PostgreSQL through add-in, I still get decimal values in the columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the TEXT function to convert the time into the text format that you require. Something like this:

```
=CONCATENATE("Istanbul: ", TEXT(A1,"hh:mm"), " and Ankara: "18:30, TEXT(A2,"hh:mm"))
```

Comment: Just when I found the solution! Thank you very much, this was really a pain and now it works like a charm!